# Qual o erro na última linha de uso de UPDATE na linguagem MySQL?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, mysql

Eu desenvolvi um projecto final sem erro, feito em Java, mas ainda tenho apenas um erro de `UPDATE` na última linha da criação de tabela `clientes` do banco de dados na linguagem MySQL. Eu estou a pedir para actualizar os dados do cadastro.

```
public void atualizaCliente(Cliente clienteEditado, String referencia){
            classeDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            stringConexao = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/biblioteca_database";
            login = "root";
            senha = "usbw";
            conn=null;
            sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

            try
            {
                Class.forName(classeDriver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConexao, login, senha);
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                int x=stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE clientes SET nome='"+clienteEditado.getNome()+"'," +
                        "end='"+clienteEditado.getEnd()+"', num='"+clienteEditado.getNum()+"'," +
                        "bairro='"+clienteEditado.getBairro()+"', cidade='"+clienteEditado.getCidade()+"'," +
                        "cpf='"+clienteEditado.getCpf()+"', tel='"+clienteEditado.getTel()+"'," +
                        "nasc='"+clienteEditado.getNasc()+"' WHERE nome='"+referencia+"';");

                if ( x == 1 )
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastro atualizado com sucesso!","",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados","",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O drive de conexão informado não encontrado","",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

E no banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `nome` TEXT COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `end` TEXT COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `num` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` TEXT COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `cidade` TEXT COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `cpf` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `tel` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `nasc` INT(10) NOT NULL
);

insert into clientes values ('', '','', '', '', '', '', '');

SELECT * FROM clientes;
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome;
DELETE from clientes WHERE nome;
UPDATE clientes SET nome;
```

Na última linha, deu um erro, de acordo com o MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Esse bloco SQL é o que foi gerado??

Comment: Eu fiz próprio código em editor de código SublimeText ou no MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa terminar o comando UPDATE.

```
 UPDATE clientes SET nome = 'um nome qualquer',
                        end = 'endereco',
                        num = 581,
                        bairro = 'bairro',
                        cidade = 'cidade',
                        cpf = '12.235.145-40',
                        tel = '123.456',
                        nasc = '25/12/2016'
```

Sua tabela de clientes precisa de um ID também. E seu comando ficaria assim:

```
 UPDATE clientes SET nome = 'um nome qualquer',
                        end = 'endereco',
                        num = 581,
                        bairro = 'bairro',
                        cidade = 'cidade',
                        cpf = '12.235.145-40',
                        tel = '123.456',
                        nasc = '25/12/2016' 
  WHERE ID = idcorrente;
```

Comment: Não tenho ID no projecto. Tenho que colocar o ID no projecto? Mas acho-o desnecessário. Colocaria 'nome' como uma referência no lugar de 'id'.

Comment: O ID normalmente é um campo onde o usuário não pode mexer, já o conteúdo do campo NOME me parece ser editável.

Comment: Então ele tem que ser editável sim, porque é uma referência para editar, excluir e actualizar.

Comment: Veja, você não pode pode alterar o ID de 1 para 2, por exemplo, porque o seu ID é o campo chave.

Comment: Preste atenção ao código em Java: 

`int x=stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE clientes SET nome='"+clienteEditado.getNome()+"', ...WHERE nome='"+referencia+"';");`